# Error using JQuery post request

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to connect to a php file using a JQuery post request but it is not working. The post function is supposed to alert success' but it does not. What seems to be the problem?

button.php

```
<button class='clickable'>Click </button>
```

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.clickable').click(function(){
      $.post("notification.php", {"op" : "notify"}, function(data){
          alert (d);  
        });    
 });
});
```

notification.php

```
if ($_REQUEST['op'] == "notify") {
    echo "success";
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are alerting the wrong local variable `alert(d)` should actually be `alert(data)`

Comment: Do you receive an error in your console?

Comment: @BrianGerhards there is no error on the console

Comment: Look at the Net tab of your developer tools. Do you see the request? Is it formatted as you expect? What about the response? Are there any other requests that you aren't expecting?

Answer (score 0):

You must change `alert (d);` to `alert (data);`

Answer (score 0):

**HTML file**

```html
<button class='clickable'>Click </button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.clickable').click(function(){
      $.post("notification.php", {"op" : "notify"}, function(data){
          alert (data);  
        });    
 });
});
</script>
```

**notification.php**

```
if ($_REQUEST['op'] == "notify") {
echo "success"; }
```